# Why was Russia never part of NATO?

Tags: russia, nato

1954 USSR proposed to join NATO and got rejected. [1991 one of Yeltsin's](http://www.nytimes.com/1991/12/21/world/soviet-disarray-yeltsin-says-russia-seeks-to-join-nato.html) long term goals was to join NATO. 2001 Putin asked Bill Clinton if Russia could join NATO and his response was "never mind". So why was USSR/Russia never permitted to join NATO? What would be downsides of them joining NATO?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far?

Comment: Maxim: What do you think was (is) NATO's purpose? Incidentally, Bill Clinton stopped to be a US president in January of 2001 and Stalin could not have asked anybody about anything while dead (even if not, technically speaking buried).

Comment: Please revise to remove factual errors.

Comment: Maxim: Fine, so with this revision, Stalin can no longer speak from his grave, but Putin is still doing something quite odd. Is there any evidence for the claims in the first three lines of your question?

Comment: @Moishe Cohen He said it at an interview. NATO neither denied nor approved it http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/06/13/watch-putin-recalls-time-considered-russia-joining-nato/

Comment: [Please revise with sources](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/633/1401).  NATO was formed to oppose Soviet block; in 1954 there was no nation "Russia".  Too many suspicious assertions with no evidence.

Comment: I think much of what you are looking for can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO%E2%80%93Russia_relations#Suggestions_of_Russia_joining_NATO Also, if you google 'Russia / Soviet Union joining NATO you'll find quite a few hits.

Answer (score 4):

This is really a question? NATO came into existence BECAUSE of the USSR. Since the USSR was seen as an aggressor in the post-WW2, bases on their behavior in Eastern Europe, some Western European and North American countries saw the need for a defense pact.
The USSR applying for membership in 1954 is nonsensical as by then they had created the Warsaw pact (1951) as a reaction to that same NATO.
This is basic history stuff - every schoolkid gets this in highschool.

Comment: The purpose of NATO: "To keep the Americans in, the Russians out, and the Germans down." https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Hastings_Ismay

Comment: Warsaw Pact: 1955-1991, RIP.

Comment: My bad - it was indeed 1955, not 1951. But that does not diminish that it would be nonsensical to admit the USSR into a pact that was intended against them anyway.

Comment: It would be nice if this answer could be edited to fit more within our [Be Nice](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Comment: Given that this is basically lesson 1 in international relations in the post-WW2 world, the questioner showed that he did not put in any effort to find the answer himself.

Comment: @MareGaea Actually, USSR did apply for NATO membership - because the stated reason for NATO founding was the preservation of peace in Europe, not containitg the USSR. When the application was declined - it confirmed the goal of the pact for Soviets. [Source](http://www.cbc.ca/news/world/fast-facts-about-nato-1.778864)